# How do I reuse oracle connection in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone assist with letting me know where I need to define the connection because I keep on getting an error. This is my first stab at this and have been at it for some time now so any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
var Oracle = require('oracle');


var connectData = {
    hostname: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 1521,
    database: "hr", // System ID (SID)
    user: "user",
    password: "password"
}

Oracle.connect = function(callback) {
    oracle_driver.connect(connectData, function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            callback(err, connection);
        }
        connection.close();
    });
}

var statement = connection.prepare("SELECT * FROM HR where rownum < :1");

function runQuery(stmt, row_num, cb) {
    stmt.execute([row_num], function(err, count) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        if (count !== 1) return cb(new Error("bad count: " + count));
        // We are done
        return cb();
    });
}


runQuery(statement, 90, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error executing query:", err);
        return;
    }

    console.log(results);
    connection.close(); // call only when query is finished executing 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the oracle driver already supports it, you should wrap your expensive resources into a [generic-pool](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generic-pool).

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/raztus/6242411) for an example of how you can create your own pool for use.

Comment: If it's not self explanatory enough could do a brief example.. but generally you setup your queue with setup/teardown methods... get a connection from the pool, use it, and return it to the pool.

Comment: Pooling looked nice but I do not think it is for Node Oracle, I do not see it listed on the dependency.

Comment: No, you create your own module that creates a generic pool, and that pool is loaded with oracle connections...